# Multiple INSERT sql query, error complains that my values are not fields

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I am sure this is just a syntax screw up, but having looked at the manual, I can't see how I'm going wrong:

```
INSERT INTO 
`2012`(country_name) 
VALUES 
(`Afghanistan`),(`Algeria`),(`Botswana`),(`Burkina Faso`)
```

Where country_name is a column in my database. However, on submitting the query I get:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Afghanistan' in 'field list'

But Afghanistan is not mean to be a field, it's a value! What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

values should be wrap with **single quotes**, not backtick

```
INSERT INTO 
`2012`(country_name) 
VALUES 
('Afghanistan'),('Algeria'),('Botswana'),('Burkina Faso')
```

backtick are used to escape columnNames and tableNames that are reserved keywords in MySQL. ex,

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`unique`, `from`, `to`) VALUES ('','','')
```

Comment: Thank you! Working late at night, hard to see the difference :) I didn't know this before, thanks for teaching, I'll accept when it lets me